# What's a good informal proof for the fact that the union of countable sets is also countable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I've seen a few proofs that are very rough, almost philosophical, using a set of all even numbers and a set of all odd numbers to show the intuitiveness of their union being countable. Whats a slightly more rigorous proof to demonstrate this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to think of the notion of 'countable'. The most formal way is probably to say that a set $A$ is countable if and only if there is an onto function $f$ from the natural numbers to $A$.  If we have such an onto function, then that means that we can 'list' all elements of set A as follows:

$f(1), f(2), f(3), ....$

So, another way (a little more informal) of thinking of a set being countable is to say that it is 'listable'. That is, if we can create a list like so:

$a_1, a_2, ...$

where each element of $A$ occurs somewhere on this list, then $A$ will be countable, since we can then simply define $f(i) = a_i$ to get our onto function. So yet another way of saying this is that the elements of $A$ are 'indexable': there is a 1st element, a 2nd, a 3rd, etc., and all elements will get 'hit' as long as we proceed with this: it is in that sense that we can still 'count' them.

Notice that the list may be infinitely long, but that is ok: as long as each element in $A$ occurs somewhere on the list. Also, duplicates on the list are ok (that is, elements from $a$ may occur multiple times on the list), since all we require is that the corresponding function $f$ is onto ... it need not be injective.

So, all we are going to do to show that some set is countable is to show that we can make it listable ... the formal function $f$ can be generated from that list in a straightforward manner as shown above.

OK, so let $A$ and $B$ be countable sets. Let's consider the following cases:

I. If both have a finite number of elements (say, $A = \{a_1,...a_n\}$ and $B = \{b_1,...b_m\}$), then we can create a list of objects like so:

$a_1,...a_n,b_1,...b_m$

(and remember, having duplicates is ok, so it doesn't matter that $A$ and $B$ may share the same elements)

II. If one set is finite and the other is not (say, $A = \{a_1,...a_n\}$ and $B = \{b_1,...\}$ (remember, since B is countable, it is 'indexable'), then we can create a list like so:

$a_1,...a_n,b_1,...$

III. If both sets are infinite (say, $A = \{a_1,...\}$ and $B = \{b_1,...\}$, then we can create a list like so:

$a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,...a_n,b_n,...$

Of course, you do **NOT** want to try and get a 'list' like so:

$a_1,...,b_1,...$

because there are infinitely many $a$'s, so there is no index for any of the $b$'s. Indeed, this is not a list at all!

And yes, maybe that is still too informal for your taste, but again, you can easily generate the corresponding onto functions from these lists.

Comment: Damn, this is exhaustive and very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisT You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the collection you have is $\{A_n: n \in \Bbb N\}$ and let $A_n = \{a_{i,n}: i \in \Bbb N\}$. WLOG, the $A_n$ are all disjoint. Then the map which sends $a_{n,m}$ to $(n,m)$ injects $\bigcup_n A_n$ into $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$, which is countable.

Comment: This is nice, but it really hides the fact that the axiom of choice (countable version) is used.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft this is not supposed to be formal or rigorous (see the title and context of the question)